# How to prove given set is a smooth manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, jacobian

I want to prove that the following set is a smooth manifold:
$$M=\{(\vec x,\vec y)\in\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n:\|\vec x-\vec y\|=1\}$$

My idea was to define $F:\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R} $ by $F(\vec x,\vec y)=\|\vec x-\vec y\|-1$, and so $M=F^{-1}(\{0\})$. One can easily check that for every $a=(\vec x,\vec y)\in M, RankJ_F(a)=1$, but I don't know how to take it from here.

Is my approach correct? what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. To finish have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem

Comment: Quick unimportant comment: computation is easier if you let $F(x,y) = \|x-y\|^2 -1$.

Comment: @AaronDaniel Is there a way to solve it without using this theorem?

Comment: I guess when following your approach of using the differentiable function F you either use this theorem or go through the steps of the proof of that theorem for your special case.  Its using arguments like that to show that charts of M exist or explicitly providing charts for M.

Comment: Your $M$ is just $\mathbb R^{n} \times \mathbb S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @ArcticChar why is this true?

Answer (score 2):

Let $L: \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$, $L(\vec x, \vec y) = (\vec x, \vec y - \vec x)$. $L$ is a diffeomorphism with inverse $(\vec x, \vec y) \mapsto (\vec x, \vec y + \vec x)$. Then

\begin{align}
L(M) &= \{(\vec x,\vec y-\vec x)\in\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n:\|\vec x-\vec y\|=1\}\\
&= \{(\vec x,\vec z)\in\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}^n:\|\vec z\|=1\}\\
&= \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb S^{n-1} 
\end{align}

is clearly a smooth manifold. Thus $M = L^{-1} (L(M))$ is also a smooth manifold.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. Why is $\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{S}^{n-1}$ is a smooth manifold? Moreover, why does that make $L^{-1}(L(M))$ a smooth manifold?

Comment: There are three things you missed: That $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is a smooth manifold, (2) product of smooth manifolds are again smooth manifolds, and (3) if $N$ is a smooth manifold and $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then $f(N)$ is also a smooth manifold. @GBA